# How to prevent FileIOPermissionException(and others) when run .NET application from network drive

Tags: exe, securityexception, network-drive

My C# application (.NET 3.5 SP1) works very well when if execeuted from local drive.

However, if I run it from a network drive, it execute (IT IS .NET 3.5 SP1), but failed to read a file located on the same network drive, during **File.ReadAllText**.

If it matter, the folder structure is like the following

```
\\server\myshare\ABC\app.exe
\\server\myshare\DEF\xxx.txt
```

I guess this is some security feature applied by .NET, they remove the "execution" limit since SP1 but the rights is not as exactly as a local application, still.

I've search around but I cannot find what's happening and what the limits are if you run it remotely.

It is a CONSOLE APPLICATION with command line argument, if it matter.